# Profile picture not updating in browser after uploading

Tags: php

I am still learning PHP. I want my the picture that i have uploaded to show after uploading. 
its uploading but its not changing the uploaded picture on the browser. 
It changes after i restart my computer.Sometimes it changes when  I change the browser. i am using Chrome. 
What could be the problem here because it is uploading and updating the database. But the uploaded picture is not changing immediately when uploaded. 
here is my code.

```html
<?php

include 'config.php';
session_start();

$user=$_SESSION['username'];

$update = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['update']);
$phone = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$pswd = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['pswd']);
$pswd2 = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['pswd2']);
//$avatar = $_POST['name'];

if ($pswd!=$pswd2)
{
 $_SESSION["message"] = "Passwords do not match. Please try again.";
 header("location:profile?error");
}

else
{
 $pswd = password_hash($pswd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

 $sql= "UPDATE students SET email='$email' WHERE username='$user'";
 $sql2 ="UPDATE students SET phonenum='$phone' WHERE username='$user'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql) and $conn->query($sql2);

if (empty($pswd) || empty($pswd2))
{
 header("location:profile");
}
else
{
  $sql3= "UPDATE students SET pswd='$pswd' WHERE username='$user'";
}
 $passresult=$conn->query($sql3);
  if($result==TRUE && $passresult==TRUE)
  {
  $_SESSION['message'] = "Profile Updated!";
  header("location:profile.php?done");
  }
}
                   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 //Targeting Folder
 $target="propics/";
 $target=$target.basename($_FILES['propic']['name']);
 //Getting Selected image Type
 $type=pathinfo($target,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 //Allow only image Format To Upload
 if($type!='jpg' && $type!='jpeg' && $type!='JPG' && $type!='PNG' && $type!='GIF'  && $type!='png' && $type!='gif'){
  echo "Only JPG,JPEG,PNG and GIF file format are allowed to Upload";
 }
 else{
  //lmit file size
  if ($_FILES['propic']['size'] > 5000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your image is too large.";        
        }
 
    else{
   
   
  $upload_success=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['propic']['tmp_name'],$target);
  if($upload_success==TRUE){
   //Getting Selected image Information

    //renaming the file to the username to avoid conflict when uploading
    $name=$user.".".$type;
    rename("propics/".$_FILES['propic']['name'],"propics/".$name); 
    //      
    $sql= "UPDATE students SET propic='$name' WHERE username='$user'";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if($result==TRUE){
 $_SESSION['message']= "Profile picture updated successfully!";
   header("location:/prac/profile.php?done");
   }
  }
  }
  
 }
}
?>
```

below is the code that is showing the picture.

```html
  <img id="mainpropic" src="propics/<?php echo $row['propic'];?>" width="200px" height="200px" >
```

Comment: You need to use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to achieve this.

Comment: Where is the HTML part

Comment: "_It shows after i restart my computer_" Really? Refreshing the page doesn't do it? The image might be in your browser's cache, try `CTRL-F5` or `Shift-F5` to reload without cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that this is a browser problem, the browser is caching the picture. If i refresh without cache everything works well.